# Changing initial conditions in agent-based voter model

Tags: netlogo, voting, agent-based-modeling

How could I change the initial conditions in [this](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/Confident%20Voter%20-%20Network) voter model?

There are agents with four opinions: negative confident, negative unsure, positive unsure, or positive confident. I'm not sure about the correct changes to make it work with setting values independently, i.e. x% negative confident, y% negative unsure, z% positive unsure and w% positive confident (x+y+z+w=100%).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not able to make sense of this question. What does "make it work with setting values independently" mean?

Comment: Presently initial opinions have equal probability. So instead of having negative confident=positive confident=0.5, I'm seeking to set negative confident=x, negative unsure=y, positive unsure=z, and positive confident=w, with x+y+z+w=1.

Comment: Okay, so what's the difficulty you encountered? What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question can be broken into two separate pieces:

- how to sample from a multinomial
- how to put interdependent variables in the interface

The first question has an [easy answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#To_simulate_a_multinomial_distribution).
The second question does not.  For example, suppose you include `3` sliders for `w`, `x`, and `y` and the compute `z=1-w-x-y`, how will you ensure `z>0`?  The easiest way around this is to allow setting all 4 independently as relative weights, and then produced your probabilities by scaling each weight (i.e., by dividing by `(w + x + y + z)`.  This way you do not have to depend on the user to set sensible combinations of the slider values.  (You can rule out having all zeros.)